# Enabling appliances with web2py on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

Hi I'm trying web2py for a simple web app I deployed to app engine. I can access the admin interface at /admin but it won't accept me uploading appliances / applications ie those files named `.w2p`. It says "unable to install application " even though the application is stated to be compatible with web2py on GAE. I tried several applications and therefore now asking here what could be the error that I'm making. It's probably more of a configuration question than a programming question. The error appears when I try to use the admin function "Upload & install packed application"
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GAE filesystem is read-only, so you're not going to be able to use the web2py admin interface to upload/unpack .w2p files (the admin application is expecting to be able to unzip the .w2p file into a filesystem, which it cannot do on GAE). You also will not be able to edit files via the admin interface on GAE. You'll have to deploy all apps to GAE in the usual way, as described [here](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Google-App-Engine) (you can also run the admin app locally and use its "Deploy on Google App Engine" functionality).

Comment: Related thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/web2py$20niklasro/flutuberwachung/BYLLlqYvjus/_gDCvTeZp_gJ